# Should we say "pull something on someone" or "pull off something on someone"? (Please see examples below)

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Which one is correct? Or are they both correct?

1.) John pulled a scam on Jane.

2.) John pulled ***off*** a scam on Jane.

Comment: 1) Both uses are a bit informal, so this isn't a matter of strict correctness. 2) I'm not sure that #2 would not be said, but these are two different usages of "pull," and #2 would not be as common. See [this definition of "pull off"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull%20off); it can apply to success in any kind of attempt.

Comment: Colloquially "to pull [something] off," usually refers to doing something difficult. For example, "He hadn't studied, but pulled off an A on the test." It might also be used for a criminal enterprise, such as, "pulled off a ban robbery," so it *might* be used in #2, but is less likjely.

Comment: Contrary to other commentators I would have said 2 was preferable. It does imply the scam worked though which perhaps 1 may not.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable in this context, but they have different meanings.

To "**pull something on** someone" means to **do something deceptive** to someone like, a scam, a prank or a practical joke.

To "**pull something off**" means **to succeed in doing something very difficult**, something that they were unlikely to accomplish, like a scam, finishing a lot of work in a short time, or holding their breath for 2 minutes.

So the difference between your two example sentences is that the second one includes the meaning that *John succeeded* in scamming Jane, and that *it was difficult* for John to scam Jane, while the first one does not say if John was successful, or if it was difficult.